# Javafx how to get a notification when the video ends

Tags: javafx

I am using Javafx mediaPlayer to run mp4 movies. How can I get a notification when my movie comes to an end? I just want to take an action once the movie is over.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(yourmediafile);
player.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //Code to run
        }
});
```

to achieve this